# Unexpected memory load with JDBM3

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

While the JDBM3 database promises (to my understanding) very small memory use when accessing and writing data I have the following problem:
Even when iterating inside the keyset of a TreeMap it seems that ALL the data are loaded on memory. So the following code:

```
    db=DBMaker.openFile("Myfile")
        .make();   
    SortedMap<Integer, double[]> MyMap=db.getTreeMap("MyMap");
    int i=0;
    final Set<Integer> keySet = MyMap.keySet();
    for (Object key : keySet) {
        System.out.println(i++);
     }
```

leads in loading all the double matrices on memory and finally to an OutOfMemory error. It seems to me that are also loaded a lot more GBs than the data themselves.
The things I have considered so far are:

- Is this a bug? Or there is some parameters when creating/opening the db (cache, transactions?) that disable this "feature"?
- Is this a bug in JDBM3 alpha 3 which I use (when there is alpha 4)? I just need to verify this before switching because there is not compatibility and I will have to do everything from scratch.
- Does this happen to the newer MapDB(formerly JDBM4)? I also need to verify this before switching.
- Or is this the normal behavior of the library for some reason?

Comment: note that disabling the cache did not work...

Comment: Have you used a heap analyser to see where all that memory is?

Comment: Yes, the Netbeans profiler shows that every vector was loaded on memory. I didn't even use the .get() method... Just iterating in the keyset!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: common cause for OOEM are writes.
JDMB3 keeps uncommited data in memory. So with large transactions you will run out of memory.
Solution is to commit every N items. Or you may disable transactions (DBMaker option) to write changes directly into file.

Second: iterating over keyset should not load all data into memory. It is bug if it does. But JDBM3 is unsupported, so I would recommend migrating to MapDB.